Optimal matching of Bernoulli random variables
Let $Z_1$, ..., $Z_n$ be a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables such that
for all $i\in\left\{1,..,n\right\}$ $Z_i\sim\mathcal{B}(p_i)$ where $p_i < 1/2$.
Define $l(x_{1:n}, y_{1:n}) = \min\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{x_i = y_i}, \sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{x_i \neq y_i}\right) $.
Do we have that $(\forall x_{1:n}\in\left\{0, 1\right\}^{n})$:
$$
E\left[l\left(Z_{1:n}, x_{1:n}\right)\right] \geq E\left[l\left(Z_{1:n}, 1..1\right)\right]?
$$
One can show the inequality holds for small $n$ (using exact calculus), and also for large $n$ using concentration inequalities. However, I can't prove it in the general case.

I don't have a clear idea, but I really want to write a proof based on a coupling. That is: write a probability model that works for computing that both scores. Write the deviations between the two. Show that the deviation has positive expected value. Annoyingly, such arguments are typically most satisfying when all deviations are strictly positive, but that won't be the case here. But it would help you start from a siuation where you get this idea that the Z_1 are mostly aligned.

Just a comment on presentation. The result is way more obvious if: 1. you consider a positive bias instead of negative; 2. you highlight the bias as soon as possible in the text: "a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables with a positif bias"

@lbra, sorry for missing some point in the question. I have deleted my previous wrong answer. Let me re-consider it :D

@GuillaumeDehaene Thank you for your response. I will think about this idea. The issue here is that the difference between the two scores does not have a closed formula so that it can be analyzed tightly...

Would this be related? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409431/a-lower-bound-for-the-expectation-of-min-x-n-x-when-x-follows-a-mathrm

Of course there's a closed formula: there's just that annoying max in the middle ^_^

@VezenBU Yes, it is quite related. However, their lower bound is not tight enough to allows us to conclude.
